# I have to perform addition on a 3d vector. The variable vector is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, vector

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector


    def __eq__(self, other):   
        return self.vector==other.vector

#above must not be changed. Below is my work.
#def __str__(self):
#     return self.vector ---Not sure how to use __str__ on a list---



    def __add__(self,other):
        vector = Vector(self.vector+other.vector)
        return vector
```

I know this is a wrong method but I have no clue how to work with a list. I just want to know how to work with a list in a class. 
Also, the following statement should work:

```
x=Vector([2,4,6]) #This is a list right? This is where I get stuck.
y=Vector([7,8,9])
print(x+y==Vector([9.12.15]))
```

I don't want the answer to all the operations just the **add** is enough. I just don't understand how to output lists in classes without the statement "a.vector" which clearly was not used the commands given above when creating objects for classes.

Also please specify if any clarification is required.
Any help is appreciated!
I am new to programming and just learnt classes in Python.
Thanks a lot on advance

Comment: You can simply zip the lists together and sum each pair of items. But The best way I think is to just use Numpy arrays that have this functionality in themselves by default plus many other useful methods for working with vectors and linear algebra in general.

Comment: Thank you! Zip works as answered below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of adding two vectors of length 3 should be a vector with 3 elements, where each element is the sum of the corresponding elements in the original two vectors.

```
def __add__(self,other):
    return Vector([a+b for a,b in zip(self.vector, other.vector)])
```

This uses [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through both the starting vectors together, and constructs the new list using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> x = Vector([2,4,6])
>>> y = Vector([7,8,9])
>>> x+y==Vector([9,12,15])
True
```

*More:*

If you want to support scalar multiplication, as indicated by your comments, then your `other` operand is not another vector, but a number. So you need to multiply each element individually by that number.

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    return Vector([a*other for a in self.vector])
__rmul__ = __mul__
```

This should allow you to perform both `v*5` and `5*v` where `v` is a `Vector` object.

```
>>> x = Vector([2,4,6])
>>> x*5==Vector([10,20,30])
True
```

*More*

Here is an example of how you might write a dot-product between two vectors:

```
def dot(self, other):
    return sum(a*b for (a,b) in zip(self.vector, other.vector))

>>> x = Vector([1,2,3])
>>> y = Vector([3,2,1])
>>> x.dot(y)
10
```

Comment: Another better alternative is to just use `map` and `operator.add`.  Like `list(map(add, [1, 2], [3, 4]))`.

Comment: @Kasramvd Better because...?

Comment: @khelwood Pure built-in, functional and more memory efficient in most of the cases that you don't want a list as result (necessarily). However, the `zip()` solution is the most ad-hoc and neat way to go at these situations and you got my up-v for that ;)).

Comment: @khelwood  how do I tackle this statement?:

Comment: `x = Vector([2,4,6])
    y=Vector([7,8,9])
    print(x*5==Vector([10, 20, 30])) 
    print(5*x==Vector([10, 20, 30]))`

Comment: @Shesps Your question says "I don't want the answer to all the operations just the add is enough" — you're asking for multiplication as well now?

Comment: But i have no clue how to do a dot product

Comment: `def __mul__(self,other):
        j= Vector([a*b for a,b in zip(self.vector, other.vector)])
        return sum(j)`     Doesnt work:(

Comment: @Shesps See the edit to my answer. That's for scalar multiplication, which you were asking about before. If you actually want the dot product, that's another thing.

Comment: Im so wsorry for sqeezing the answer from you. But thanks a lot. I learnt a lot from you. Once again so sorry

Comment: So when I did the zip statement for multiplication it worked fine but how do i sum the elements of the Vector. such as for the return of the addition, how do I sum the elements if I need to?(Becasue for the dot porduct)

Comment: `def __mul__(self,other):
        return print(Vector([a*b for a,b in zip(self.vector, other.vector)]))`

Comment: The products for each work out but how do i sum the elements to get te dot product? Please forgive me foe asking this@khelwood

Comment: I've added an implementation of a dot product.